# Python: Need to extract tag content from html page using regex, but not BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, html, regex, tags, substring

I have a requirement wherein I have to extract content inside `<raw>` tag. For example I need to extract `abcd` and `efgh` from this html snippet:
 `<html><body><raw somestuff>abcd</raw><raw somesuff>efgh</raw></body></html>`

I used this code in my python
  `re.match(r'.*raw.*(.*)/raw.*', DATA)`

But this is not returning any substring. I'm not good at regex. So a correction to this or a new solution would help me a great deal. 
I am not supposed to use external libs (due to some restriction in my company).

Comment: for your enjoyment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags

Comment: not sure how often this question has been asked?

Comment: "I am not supposed to use external libs (due to some restriction in my company)"  That's a very, very bad idea.  Your company is wasting time and money having you trying to reinvent an existing, working, correct, widely-used solution.

Comment: Or the company is a school, and the assignment is a homework ;)

Answer (score 5):

Your company really needs to rethink their policy. Rewriting an XML parser is a complete waste of time, there are already several for Python. Some are included in the stdlib, so if you can `import re` you should also be allowed to `import xml.etree.ElementTree` or anything else listed at http://docs.python.org/library/markup.html .

You really should be using one of those. No sense duplicating all of that work.

Answer (score 0):

Using non greedy matching (*?) can do this easily, at least for your example.

`re.findall(r'<raw[^>]*?>(.*?)</raw>', DATA)`

Comment: Sadly, it won't work in general.  But it will appear to work for a while.

Comment: That's not a very helpful comment @S.Lott, what exactly are you referring to?

Comment: @Rob Young: A regular expression for a language like XML or HTML can be defeated by deeply nested tags of the same type.  So a `<raw><raw></raw></raw>` structure will defeat any RE.

Comment: @S.Lott I thought I was being cute in the remark, but I guess I should have been more explicit than just noting 'at least for your example.'

Comment: Not everyone gets the limitations of regular expressions.  As you can see by the number of Stack Overflow questions from people trying to parse HTML or XML with RE's.